# Will i get an IPN on completion of payment review in Paypal?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I am currently working on a project using PayPal. When I made a transaction, the payment status in the IPN received was `'Pending'` and reason was `Payment review`. I found out that it will take 24 hours for the review process. So I want know if I will get an IPN when the review process is over?

Answer (score 1):

You should get an IPN notification when the transaction changes status. For example, PayPal sends you an IPN notifying you of a pending payment. PayPal later sends you a second IPN telling you that the payment has completed.

Answer (score 1):

Because of security reasons you may get the first IPN with payment status pending But when the payment review is over You will get another IPN with payment status as completed.You can can transfer your stuffs then.The payment review will take maximum 24 hours.